How to ensure FCM token freshness on iOS?
I have a React native app that is used to schedule some payment related notifications in the future. Sometimes these notifications can be scheduled for up to a year from now. I tried using local notifications, but the limit of 64 does not fit the requirements of the app.
After a couple of days of research, I've decided to use Push notifications and send a periodical background notification to users whose tokens are starting to become a bit stale. (5 days or older)
As the FCM documentation states, the token becomes stale after 28 days. I would like to keep it fresh in order users to receive the notifications they've scheduled.
Is the background push reliable way to deal with this problem on iOS? How are big apps sending push notifications even after months of inactivity?
